# Standard deviation between specific value and last value in a column

Tags: excel, standards, deviation

I would like to calculate the standard deviation of a population of many values, while the last value changes daily. Therefore, I would like to specify the range for the calculation from field `G21` to whatever the last value in column `G` is.

I have been trying the formula for the lastest value, and this returns an error. The formula I am trying to use is:

```
=STDEVP($G$21:(LOOKUP(9.99E+307,$G$22:$G1000)))
```

How could I do this?

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=STDEVP($G$21:INDEX($G$22:$G1000,MATCH(9.99E+307,$G$22:$G1000)))
```